# Curve equidistant to sine and cosine.

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, plane-curves

If I have the sine and cosine curves plotted, what would be the formula of the curve that is equidistant to both curves? Here's a picture of how it looks like.

[image]

The original question comes from a reddit post, I have worked on it for a bit but don't even know where to start.

I have no idea about how to even find the closest point on the cosine graph given a point on the sine graph. I suspect the answer would not be very nice, a closed form may not even exist.

Edit: the Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/487lfw/a_problem_that_has_been_bothering_me_for_a_while/?sort=confidence

Comment: Equidistant isn't always the same as average. Average is only equidistant vertically. I wonder if that's what the OP meant. Given the OP's talking about maybe not having a closed form I suspect the OP is after more than an average.

Comment: @IanMiller I have edited my post just now.

Comment: "I have no idea about how to even find the closest point on the cosine graph given a point on the sine graph." This is not even related to your question. "I suspect the answer would not be very nice, a closed form may not even exist." Yeah, as explained at length on the page you link to (where they also show "where to start" so how comes that you "don't even know where to start"?).

Comment: Not an answer, but you may be interested in reading about the [medial axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) (in your situation, for the bounded region $\cos x \leq y \leq \sin x$, $\pi/4 \leq x \leq 5\pi/4$; the other regions can be handled by symmetry).

Comment: Maybe too "naif" but, at the first seeing, is it not $\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}?$

Comment: @Piquito Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. It is not the answer, because the arithmetic mean at every $x$ is only the average height of the curve at certain $x$, but not the shortest distance. Maybe I should have been clearer that I wanted shortest distance

Comment: I understand clearly now. You ask about two inf of distances. Thank you.

Comment: @Bubububu There are a lot of ways the adjective $equidistant$ translates mathematically. Suppose we have a curve that is at midpoint and normal to sin&cos, would that do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a point $(x_s,\sin(x_s))$ on the sin curve and a point $(x_c,\cos(x_c))$ on the cos curve. The normals to the curves at these points are:

$$y=\sin(x_c)+\cos(x_s)(x-x_s)$$
$$y=\cos(x_s)-\sin(x_c)(x-x_c)$$

Solving simultaneously gives the point of intersection $(x_i,y_i)$.

$$(x_i,y_i)=\left(\frac{\cos(x_c)-\sin(x_s)+x_s\sin(x_c)+x_c\cos(x_s)}{\sin(x_c)+cos(x_s)},\frac{\cos(x_c)\cos(x_s)+\sin(x_s)\sin(x_)+x_c\cos(x_s)\sin(x_c)-x_s\cos(x_s)\sin(x_c)}{\sin(x_s)+\cos(x_c)}\right)$$

Next we want to solve such that the distances are equal:

$$\left(\frac{\cos(x_c)-\sin(x_s)+(x_c-x_s)\sin(x_c)}{\sin(x_s)+\cos(x_c)}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\cos(x_s)(\cos(x_c)-\sin(x_s)+(x_c-x_s)\sin(x_c))}{\sin(x_s)+\cos(x_c)}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\cos(x_c)-\sin(x_s)+(x_s-x_c)\cos(x_s)}{\sin(x_s)+\cos(x_c)}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sin(x_c)(\sin(x_s)-\cos(x_c)+(x_c-x_s)\cos(x_s))}{\sin(x_s)+\cos(x_c)}\right)^2$$

Removing denominator and factorizing gives:

$$(1+\cos(x_s)^2)(\cos(x_c)-\sin(x_s)+(x_c-x_s)\sin(x_c))^2=(1+\sin(x_c)^2)(\cos(x_c)-\sin(x_s)+(x_c-x_s)\cos(x_s))^2$$

This doesn't have a closed form for $x_s$ in terms of $x_c$ (or vice versa) so we can't express the distance in terms of just one of $x_s$ or $x_c$ let alone try to minimize it so I'm pretty confident there is no closed form for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am more than convinced that the curve doesn't have closed form now

Comment: There is certainly a differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a point $P=(a,b)\in [0,2\pi]\space\text{x}\space [-1,1]$; the squares of the distances of $P$ to the curves $y= \sin x$ and $y=\cos x$ are
$$D_1(x)=(x-a)^2+(\sin x-b)^2\\D_2(x)= (x-a)^2+(\cos x-b)^2$$
The extremum of these two fonctions can be got taking derivatives so
$$D_1’(x)=2x+\sin 2x-2b\cos x-2a\\D_2’(x)=2x-\sin 2x+2b\sin x-2a$$
The equations $$D_1’(x)=0\\D_2’(x)=0$$ are trascendental; furthermore, using slider control you can see that these equations can have both, just one real root or exactly three real roots. Among these roots of transcendental equations are the corresponding to the minimum of $\sqrt{D_i}; i=1,2$.

We can ensure that it is quite improbable a closed form for the searched function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that it is improbable to solve this problem in closed form. An extra note, I think another difficulty here is that let's say we had solved $D'_1(x_1)=0$ and $D'_2(x_2)=0$, we still have to solve for $a,b$ such that $D_1(x_1)=D_2(x_2)$.

Comment: That is exactly, "we still...." (I tought at this before my "quite improbable")